# Python Django HTML csrf token not working

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to put in a csrf token in my post form but I keep getting an error that I cant quite debug

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block title %}Data Services{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<h1>{{ deal_name }}</h1>
<a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/pick/">Return to Deals here</a>
<p>Which lender do you need to send an email to? </p>
{% if unpaid %}
<form action="/pick/{{ type_id }}/lenders/" method="post">{% csrf token %}
    <select name="email_name">
            {% for l in unpaid %}
            <option value="{{ l.name }}">{{ l.name }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Email">
    </form>
    {% endif %}
<div>
    <ul>
    {% if lender %}
        There are {{ lender|length }} lenders who have paid.
        {% for l in lender %}
            <li> {{ l.name }} </li>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        <li> As of now no Lenders have been recorded as paid. </li>
    {% endif %}
    </ul>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

my error:

Invalid block tag on line 10: 'csrf', expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Like am i missing something here? I have done attempts like these multiple times with success.

Comment: accept one of the answers. Its common practice ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tag is `{% csrf_token %}`, not `{% csrf token %}`.

Comment: I guess ive been working too hard because that was pretty dumb. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the tag correctly. No space between both words:

```
{% csrf_token %}
```

You could over the tutorial on CSRF (again) to ensure all the other necessary parts are in place:

[Cross Site Request Forgery protection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/).